# After UnMuting Mic in WebRTC there's a severe Local Loopback (Own Voice) problem

Tags: javascript, webrtc

We've successfully implemented WebRTC is our system for Audio Call and Video Call including the CoTurn STUN/TURN server etc.

All is working fine until we decided to implement a Mute Mic and Mute Webcam function (for Local Stream only) where we can still see or hear other party but they cant see or hear us.

When Muting the Mic (Local Stream) it works as it should with no problems but when we UnMute the Mic there seems to be a severe Loopback (we hear our own voice) from our Local Stream.

This behavior is `ONLY IN CHROME` we're using the latest Version 83.0.4103.97 (Official Build) (64-bit). We tried in the latest Firefox but this behavior is not there.

No matter what we tried we cant seem to eliminate this severe Loopback issue. I hope some friends here can help us please.

Here is our code that we currently use ;

```
var isMute = false;
$(document).on('click','#audio_mute_div',function(){
    var localStream = connection.attachStreams[0];
    console.log(localStream);
    if(isMute==false){
          isMute = true;;
          localStream.mute('audio');
          $('.audio_mute').attr('src','./assets/mute.png');
    }else{
         isMute = false;
         localStream.unmute('audio');
         $('.audio_mute').attr('src','./assets/audio.png');
    }
});

var isVideoMute = false;
$(document).on('click','#video_mute_div',function(){
    var localStream = connection.attachStreams[0];
    if(isVideoMute==false){
           isVideoMute = true;
           localStream.mute('video');
           $('.video_mute').attr('src','./assets/no-video.png');
    }else{
         isVideoMute = false;
         localStream.unmute('video');
         $('.video_mute').attr('src','./assets/video-camera.png');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you local audio/video element is muted or has the volume set to 0.
This is one of the more common mistakes in WebRTC.

Comment: We did the Mute actually works it's just when we UnMute the Mic then the Loopback starts (in Chrome). Strangely in this condition if we Mute the WebCam then the loopback STOPS...

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this problem by simply adding this line ;

connection.streamEvents.selectFirst('local').mediaElement.muted=true;

in the UnMute Function, so now the function looks like this ;

```
isMute = false;
localStream.unmute('audio');
connection.streamEvents.selectFirst('local').mediaElement.muted=true;
$('.audio_mute').attr('src','./assets/audio.png');
```

It solved the Loopback issue and it took me 5 days to look for this solution and finally found it here - https://www.rtcmulticonnection.org/docs/unmute/